# IIS7.5 and the MSBuild Extension Pack: Is it possible to specify credentials for a web application's physical path?

Tags: msbuild, iis-7.5, msbuildextensionpack

I'm writing an MSBuild installer for a web application that's hosted on IIS7.5

Up until now, setting up the web app has been a manual process using IIS Manager.

The process involves setting up credentials for the application's Physical Path but I'm struggling to find out how to do this with the extension pack.

Does anyone know:

1. if it's possible to achieve this?
2. how?
3. which version of the extension pack supports it?

Tia,
Mike

Comment: You can use PowerShell to accomplish this if that is in your scope. http://superuser.com/questions/592634/set-physical-path-credentials-in-iis7-using-powershell

Comment: Thanks Mitul I'll give that a try if I need finer grain control over credentials

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way of doing this using the extension pack to set Virtual Directory 
Defaults I've posted my answer in case it helps anyone else down the line. Mitul's comment is also worth trying for anyone needing finer grain control.

The version of the extension pack we were using was rather old. In the current version, the ConnectAsUser and ConnectAsUserPassword properties of the Iis7Website class can be used to set the default username and password for the website's virtual directories:

```
<MSBuild.Web.ExtensionPack.Web.Iis7WebSite
    ConnectAsUser="foo"
    ConnectAsUserPassword="sesame"
    ...other properties>
</MSBuild.Web.ExtensionPack.Web.Iis7WebSite>
```

Thanks,
Mike